# Mount usbfs on linux 3.10 kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, mount, initrd

I did upgrade linux kernel from 2.6 to 3.10 version
In init nn 2.6 I did mount usbfs `mount -t usbfs usbfs /proc/bus/usb -onodev,nosuid,noexec`

To enable usbfs I did `CONFIG_USB_DEVICEFS=y` and `CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_CLASS=y` in kernel's config
but they are obsolete in 3.10 kernels

So how yo emulate usbfs on 3.10 kernel?
I found the folowing topic https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/488274

Where is adviced to make

```
mount --bind /dev/bus /proc/bus
ln -s /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices /proc/bus/usb/devices
```

but `mount --bind /dev/bus /proc/bus` says me

```
mount: special device /dev/bus does not exist
```

There is no `/dev/bus` at all

Does anybody have thoughts which can help me?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The cause of this issue is that `libusb` looks in `/dev/bus/usb`, but recent kernels move this into `sysfs` under `/sys/bus/usb`.

What I did was `ln -s /sys/bus /dev/bus` to create a `symlink` from `dev` to `sys` so that `libusb` could find the usb subsystem.

Alternately, you can use a bind mount. The problem with your command is that the target mount point needs to exist before the bind mount can succeed. In this case `mkdir /dev/bus`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to get my C program working with my usb-attached LCD on a SuperMicro box running CentOS 7.  With usbfs deprecated, the /proc/bus/usb libraries moved.  In /etc/rc.local:

```
#
/usr/bin/mount --bind /dev/bus /proc/bus
/usr/bin/ln -s /sys/bus /dev/bus
/usr/bin/ln -s /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices /proc/bus/usb/devices
```

I also had to update my grub2 kernel boot parameters in /etc/default/grub  (and then run grub2-mkconfig) to get my ole "eth0" naming standards back so that I can edit the network configs via the lcd panel:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```